# relational operator expression order

Tags: c#, operators, logical-operators

This is probably a silly question, but curiosity has gotten the better of me. I've been seeing code lately that seems to "reverse" the order of expressions for relational operators e.g.:

```
if (0 == someVariable)
```

As opposed to what I normally see/write:

```
if (someVariable == 0)
```

To me, the second method seems more readable and intuitive, so I'm wondering if there's some reason I'm seeing the first method? Logically, both statements evaluate to the same result, so is it just a matter of personal preference how they're written?

Comment: thanks for the answers everyone! my curiosity has been fulfilled.

Comment: Good question, Adam. I was about to ask exactly the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand that this is personal preference. Although by putting the variable second you can ensure that you don't accidentally assign the constant to the variable which used to concearn c developers. This is probably why you are seeing it in c# as developers switch language.

Answer (score 2):

Order does not matter, however, the former implies that it
s the zero you're checking. Convention dictates the use of hte latter.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason in C and C++ is that it is easy to type

```
if (someVariable = 0) {
    ...
}
```

which always fails and also sets `someVariable` to 0.

I personally prefer the variable-first style because it reads more naturally, and just hope I don't forget to use `==` not `=`.

Many C and C++ compilers will issue a warning if you assign a constant inside an `if`.
Java and C# avoid this problem by forbidding non-boolean expressions in `if` clauses.
Python avoids this problem by making assignments a statement, not an expression.

Answer (score 1):

The first method exists as a way to remind yourself not to do assignments in an IF statement, which could have disasterous consequences in some languages (C/C++). In C# you'll only get bitten by this if you're setting booleans.

Potentially fatal C code:

```
if (succeeded = TRUE)
{
    // I could be in trouble here if 'succeeded' was FALSE
}
```

In C/C++, any variable is susceptible to this problem of VAR = CONSTANT when you intended VAR == CONSTANT. So, it is often the custom to reorder your IF statement to receive a compile error if you flub this up:

```
if (TRUE = succeeded)
{
    // This will fail to compile, and I'll fix my mistake
}
```

In C# only booleans are susceptible to this, as only boolean expressions are valid in an if statement.

```
if (myInteger = 9)
{
    // this will fail to compile
}
```

So, in the C# world it isn't necessary to adopt the CONSTANT == VAR style, unless you're comfortable with doing so.

Answer (score 1):

The latter format is a left-over from C-syntax, where, if you inadvertently left out one of the equals-signs, it did an assignment, instead of a comparison.

However, you can of course not assign to a numeric literal, so if you wrote it like the second example, you would get a compiler error, and not a bug.

In C#, however, you cannot inadvertently do this, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: If you are the sort of person who does  `if (is_error == false) ...` then you could conceivably write `if (is_error = false) ..` and the C# compiler would accept it. Not very likely to happen, but a sufficiently perverse programmer could manage it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to equality I often come across code like

```
if (0 > number)
```

or

```
if (NULL != pointer)
```

where there isn't even any danger of making a mistake in C/C++! It's one of those situations where a well-intentioned teaching technique has turned into a plain bad habit.