# Equality operator while checking condition in C++

Tags: visual-c++

IS there a difference between  these two conditions:

`if (a==5)` and `if (5==a)`?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91994/relational-operator-expression-order

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference at all.

People used to write this expression `5==a` instead of `a==5` so the could catch `a=5` errors on **C/C++** where that expression is perfectly valid and always evaluates to `true`. That way, if programmer writes (by mistake) the expression `5=a` then it will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

The two are normally the same.

Some people recommend putting the constant first (`if (5==a)`) because this way, if you mis-type and leave out one of the `=` to get: `if (5=a)`, the compiler will give an error message, whereas `if (a=5)` will compile and execute, but probably not do what you want.

Some compilers will give a warning for the latter (e.g., recent iterations of gnu do) but others don't (and Visual C++ is among the latter).

Answer (score 1):

If 'a' points to an object that overrides ==, then you may get different results in theory.